# Crystal report does not display the page

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, boolean, constraints, alphanumeric

```
    @BarId AS INTEGER
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN

    select a.*, b.remark from 
    (
    SELECT
    min(bardetailid) as BarDetailId, 
    min(barid) as BarId,
    min(Member) as Member,
    min(MemberNo) as MemberNo,
    min(BarMark) as BarMark,
    [TypeSize] , 
    min(BarLength) as BarLength,
    min(BarNo) as BarNo,
    min(BarTotal) as BarTotal,
    [ShapeCode] ,
     CAST(MAX(CAST(ShapeImage AS VARBINARY(MAX))) AS IMAGE) as ShapeImage,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.dima <> 0 THEN 
             'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
        ELSE '' 
      END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dimb <> 0 THEN 
               ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dimc <> 0 THEN 
               ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dimd <> 0 THEN 
               ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dime <> 0 THEN 
               ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dimf <> 0 THEN 
               ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dimg <> 0 THEN 
               ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dimn <> 0 THEN 
               ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END
      AS Dimension,
      min(DimA) AS DimA,
      min(DimB) AS DimB,
      min(DimC) AS DimC,
      min(DimD) AS DimD,
      min(DimE) AS DimE,
      min(DimF) AS DimF,
      min(DimG) AS DimG,
      min(DimN) AS DimN,
      min(Active) AS Active,
      min(c.CreatedDtTm) AS CreatedDtTm,
      min(createdby) as CreatedBy, 
      min(createdip) AS [CreatedIp],
      min(UpdatedDtTm) as [UpdatedDtTm],
      min(UpdatedBy) AS [UpdatedBy],
      min(UpdatedIp) AS [UpdatedIp]
    FROM            bar_schedule_detail c
    WHERE           active = 1 
    AND             barid = @BarId    
    GROUP BY
    [TypeSize],      
    [ShapeCode] , 
    CASE 
        WHEN dima <> 0 THEN 
             'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
        ELSE '' 
      END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimb <> 0 THEN 
               ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimc <> 0 THEN 
               ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimd <> 0 THEN 
               ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dime <> 0 THEN 
               ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimf <> 0 THEN 
               ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimg <> 0 THEN 
               ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimn <> 0 THEN 
               ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END
        ) as a, bar_schedule_detail b
       where a.typesize = b.typesize
       and a.shapecode = b.shapecode
       and 
      (
      CASE 
        WHEN b.dima <> 0 THEN 
      'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
    END + 
    CASE 
     WHEN b.dimb <> 0 THEN 
        ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
     WHEN b.dimc <> 0 THEN 
        ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
     WHEN b.dimd <> 0 THEN 
        ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
     WHEN b.dime <> 0 THEN 
        ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
    END + 
    CASE 
     WHEN b.dimf <> 0 THEN 
        ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
     END + 
    CASE 
     WHEN b.dimg <> 0 THEN 
        ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
    END + 
    CASE 
     WHEN b.dimn <> 0 THEN 
        ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
    END
    ) = a.dimension
    and a.CreatedDtTm = b.CreatedDtTm
    and b.active = 1 
    and b.barid = @BarId    
    ORDER BY
    substring(a.TypeSize,1,1) desc, 
    BarLength desc
    END
    END
```

[image: Error in Crystal Report]

Crystal report does not display the page when i debug the code as showed above. When i execute the code in my Sql Server, everything is executed correctly. Due to the limitation of my knowledge in programming. Can someone identify the issue that i am facing.

Comment: change data type from varchar to nvarchar

Comment: @Mahendra Same problem still persist when changing value. 

I have tried many ways such as 
AND MEMBER IN ( SELECT MIN(MEMBER) FROM BAR_SCHEDULE_DETAIL WHERE Member like '%[^0-9]%' and active = 1 and barid = @BarId) at the where clause, but still does not work. 

It shows the report but with only 1 records, its better then the previous problem i had which is getting an error message.

Comment: just provide sample data and the desire output required.

Comment: I think the problem has not been identified yet. It seems like it occurs because of other related stuff. I removed the alphabet input from the member and the program still produce error, let me check again. I double confirm later

Comment: @Mahendra I have solved the issue I put this code and a.BarDetailId = b.BarDetailId below and a.shapecode = b.shapecode and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding this code  `a.BarDetailId = b.BarDetailId and a.shapecode = b.shapecode` and it worked.